# JSONRenderer won't serialize: b'{"id":"11122211133311"}' is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've problem with serializing object using JSONRenderer.

I'm using `django-rest-framework` and I've serialized object:

```
  pk = kwargs['pk']
  tube = Tube.objects.get(id=pk)

  serialized_tube = TubeSerializer(tube)
```

`serialized_tube.data` looks like this:

> {'id': '11122211133311'}

Unfortunately I can't serialize this using JSONRenderer, because the code

```
  tube_json = JSONRenderer().render(serialized_tube.data)
  return Response(tube_json)
```

gives following error

> b'{"id":"11122211133311"}' is not JSON serializable

whereas

```
  tube_json = json.dumps(serialized_tube.data)
  return Response(tube_json)
```

works well...

I'm using Python3.4.3

Comment: the error message `b'{"id":"11122211133311"}' is not JSON serializable` suggests that `serialized_tube.data` is already json serialized (you already have a string)

Comment: It's very strange, because I'm just following this tutorial: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in your `JSONRenderer()` line, but in the line below it where you return it as a `Response`.

Django REST framework provides a custom `Response` object that will automatically be rendered as whatever the accepted renderer was, converting native Python structures into a rendered version (in this case, JSON structures). So a Python dictionary will be converted to a JSON object, and a Python list will be converted to a JSON array, etc.

Right now you are serializing your data to a JSON string *then* passing it to `Response`, where you are expecting it to be re-serialized into JSON. You can't serialize a string into JSON (you need an object or array wrapping it), which is why you are seeing the error.

The solution is to not call `JSONRenderer` ahead of time, and just pass the serializer data to `Response`.